# LARAVEL: How to display data from bootstrap modal?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-blade

I'm having problems with displaying data from modal. It works outside the modal but inside modal it only iterates 1 data.

```
@foreach ($addresses->sortByDesc('status') as $address)   
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="row g-0 flex-column">{{-- EDIT --}}
                                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 col-xxl-5 d-flex justify-content-between">

                                                    <p style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold; visibility: {{ $address->status === 'default' ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }};">Default Delivery Address</p>                                                   
                                                    <button class="btn d-inline-flex" type="button" style="font-size: 14px;text-decoration: underline;padding: 0px;font-weight: bold;height: 21px;" data-bs-target="#edit-delivery-address-modal" data-bs-toggle="modal">Edit</button>
                                                    <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="edit-delivery-address-modal">
                                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                                 
                                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Delivery Address</h4>
                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                                </div>

                                                                <div class="modal-body">
```

I want to display the addresses' relative datas when I click their Edit buttons. I tried ChatGPT's advice in putting data- in the Edit button but I'm not familiar with it so I don't know how it works. Is there a way to transfer data to modal without using js or ajax?

Comment: Livewire do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without JS.
Blade is a template language, it renders only once when the page is loaded.

Consider to use [Livewire](https://livewire.laravel.com) package to do this dynamically or use some other JS framework or library.

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish this task, JavaScript will be required in the shape of LiveWire, which seamlessly integrates with Laravel and simplifies the implementation process.

```
<!-- Example Bootstrap Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" arialabelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @if($modalData)
                          <!-- Display your data here -->
                    @else
                          <p>No data available</p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can wire up the modal to open when a user clicks on a specific element.

Open Modal

In livewire class this property bind with this function

```
public function loadData()
{
    // Fetch data and assign it to the $this->modalData property
    $this->modalData = // Fetch your data here
}
```